# Error XML deserializacion a objetos C# No se reconoce el tipo especificado:

Tags: c#, xml, object

Estoy intentando realizar la deserialización de un xml a un objeto. El problema es que cuando intento realizar esta operacion obtengo el siguiente error:

{"No se reconoce el tipo especificado: nombre='ProductTransfer', espacio de nombres='http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages', en http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages'>."}

El xml que intento deserializar es un poco grande, así que muestro parte donde el error me referencia este el problema:

```
  <TransferInfo xsi:type="ProductTransfer">
        <Code>0|0|0</Code>
        <DescriptionList>
            <Description type="GENERAL" languageCode="ENG">Private hire with driver</Description>
            <Description type="PRODUCT" languageCode="ENG">Premium product type</Description>
            <Description type="VEHICLE" languageCode="ENG">Minibus</Description>
        </DescriptionList>
        <ImageList>
            <Image>
                <Type>S</Type>
                <Url>http://transferstatic.hotelbeds.com/giata/transfers/TRD/small/prvt-prm-mnbs.png</Url>
            </Image>
            <Image>
                <Type>M</Type>
                <Url>http://transferstatic.hotelbeds.com/giata/transfers/TRD/medium/prvt-prm-mnbs.png</Url>
            </Image>
            <Image>
                <Type>L</Type>
                <Url>http://transferstatic.hotelbeds.com/giata/transfers/TRD/large/prvt-prm-mnbs.png</Url>
            </Image>
            <Image>
                <Type>XL</Type>
                <Url>http://transferstatic.hotelbeds.com/giata/transfers/TRD/extralarge/prvt-prm-mnbs.png</Url>
            </Image>
        </ImageList>
        <Type code="P"/>
        <VehicleType code="K"/>
        <TransferSpecificContent id="1129">
            <GenericTransferGuidelinesList>
                <TransferBulletPoint id="VINT">
                    <Description>INTERNATIONAL FLIGHTS</Description>
                    <DetailedDescription>For International flights, you are advised to be at the airport 3 hours before the departure of the flight.</DetailedDescription>
                </TransferBulletPoint>
                <TransferBulletPoint id="VDOM">
                    <Description>DOMESTIC FLIGHTS</Description>
                    <DetailedDescription>For domestic flights, you are advised to be at the airport 2 hours before the departure of the flight.</DetailedDescription>
                </TransferBulletPoint>
                <TransferBulletPoint id="VOUC">
                    <Description>VOUCHER </Description>
                    <DetailedDescription>Remember to bring this voucher and valid photo ID with you</DetailedDescription>
                </TransferBulletPoint>
                <TransferBulletPoint id="CHAC">
                    <Description>CHANGE OF ACCOMMODATION</Description>
                    <DetailedDescription>If you change your accommodation during your holiday, you must inform us at least 48 hours before the departure of your flight so that we can update the details of your transfer.</DetailedDescription>
                </TransferBulletPoint>
                <TransferBulletPoint id="SPLU">
                    <Description>SPECIAL LUGGAGE</Description>
                    <DetailedDescription>In the event of extra luggage or sport equipment being checked in, please contact us, as this may carry an extra charge.</DetailedDescription>
                </TransferBulletPoint>
                <TransferBulletPoint id="STFF">
                    <Description>CAN'T FIND STAFF </Description>
                    <DetailedDescription>In the event of being unable to locate a staff member, please call the emergency number indicated in this voucher.</DetailedDescription>
                </TransferBulletPoint>
                <TransferBulletPoint id="LGPR">
                    <Description>LUGGAGE PROBLEMS</Description>
                    <DetailedDescription>In the event of a problem with customs or luggage,  please call the emergency number in order to advise of the delay and take the necessary steps.</DetailedDescription>
                </TransferBulletPoint>
                <TransferBulletPoint id="CHFL">
                    <Description>CHANGE OF FLIGHT </Description>
                    <DetailedDescription>If you change your return flight during your holiday, you must inform us at least 48 hours before the departure of your flight so that we can update the details of your transfer.</DetailedDescription>
                </TransferBulletPoint>
                <TransferBulletPoint id="CBBS">
                    <Description>CHILDBOOSTER / BABY SEAT</Description>
                    <DetailedDescription>Child car seats and boosters are not included unless specified in your booking and can carry an extra cost. Should you need to book them, please contact your point of sale prior to travelling.</DetailedDescription>
                </TransferBulletPoint>
            </GenericTransferGuidelinesList>
            <MaximumWaitingTime time="30">minutes</MaximumWaitingTime>
            <MaximumWaitingTimeSupplierDomestic time="15">minutes</MaximumWaitingTimeSupplierDomestic>
        </TransferSpecificContent>
    </TransferInfo>
```

Parte del objeto que estaria relacionado con el xml es el suguiente:

```
 [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = 
 "http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages")]
  [XmlRoot(ElementName="TransferInfo", 
  Namespace="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages")]
  public class TransferInfo {


    [XmlElement(ElementName="Code", 
   Namespace="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="DescriptionList", 
    Namespace="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages")]
    public DescriptionList DescriptionList { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ImageList", 
    Namespace="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages")]
    public ImageList ImageList { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Type", 
    Namespace="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages")]
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute (AttributeName="type", 
    Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string _Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="VehicleType", 
    Namespace="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages")]
    public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="TransferSpecificContent", 
     Namespace="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages")]
    public TransferSpecificContent TransferSpecificContent { get; set; }
}
```

EL codigo que estoy usando para la deserializacion es el siguiente:

```
        // objeto a transformar 
        var testObject = new TransferValuedAvailRS();
        var xmlSerialzer = new XmlSerializer(testObject.GetType());
       //responseStream es un stream
        var responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(responseStr))
        {   //deserializacion a objeto
            var result = xmlSerialzer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

Como puedo solucionar este error. alguna sugerencia? Agradezco su ayuda. un saludo amigos.

Answer (score 2):

El error que te sale es porque tu XML no puede acceder al namespace http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages.

Generalmente cuando se usa un namespace este refiere a un archivo XSD que valida la sintaxis de los tags que pertenecen a ese namespace. Por lo tanto ese archivo XSD debe ser publico, para que terceros como es tu caso no tengan problemas. Pegue la url del namespace en el navegador y me pide un login. Ese mismo problema es el que presenta tu deserealización:

```
{"No se reconoce el tipo especificado: nombre='ProductTransfer', espacio de nombres='http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages', en http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages'>."}
```

No programo en C# así que no se como solucionarlo (bueno si: resuelve lo del acceso), pero por lo menos ya te dije la causa del problema.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo. saludos